# Steam will not run (missing libGL.so.1)

Tags: package-management, dependencies, steam

I'm trying to install Steam on the laptop my son is getting for christmas (running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS), however when I try to run Steam for the first time (via the "Steam" desktop icon it creates), a Terminal window appears and I am told:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

Entering the password does its thing, then I am told:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-java-trusty.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-java-trusty.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I press "Enter" and am told in a pop-up dialog box:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
```

I have followed the answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402066/steam-needs-libgl1-mesa-drii386-libgl1-mesa-glxi386), however it had no effect...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is installed on the laptop?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386` respectively? Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. :-)

Comment: Is this a new install. you should have no problems installing `steam` what so ever. have you added ppa's to the system. and are your repositories enabled in Software & updates ?

Comment: It was a new install, on a "clean" system (i.e. a system that has only just had a fresh install of Ubuntu)... But the issue is now resolved, as indicated below.

Answer (score -1):

Its a fairly common problem with Ubuntu, you probably have all of the dependencies needed, but for unknown reasons Canonical adds the word ubuntu to most lib files.

An easy work around is to do an online search for ligGL.1, NOT IN THE SOFTWARE CENTRE, download and install IT.

It will then work, as it's what I had to do from 13.05 on.

Comment: This answer would fit probably on 90 % of Stack Exchange questions ^^ However, this might help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005

Comment: That worked, but not until I did "sudo apt-get install -y steam" at the end... Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)